Consequences of the false assumption about the existence of a population distribution in the statistical inference, when working with real-world data
Statistical inference methods, e.g., statistical hypothesis tests, assume that the observed data was sampled from a population distribution. In the case of real-world data, it's a great simplification. For example, ratings of a specific movie on imdb.com are not sampled from any distribution. They, instead, are a combination of multiple factors like the cast, acting, sounding, the mood of the viewer, etc.
From what I understand, it's perfectly fine to make false assumptions about data as long as we can evaluate what error these assumptions introduce. For example, we have a Naive Bayes model in Machine Learning, which assumes that the features are conditionally independent, given the target class. For many datasets, it's false. But we have a test set, a portion of the whole dataset, that allows us to evaluate the error of such a model built on the foundation of false assumptions.
In the case of statistical hypotheses testing, we are not provided with a way to evaluate such errors. In my understanding, any result of statistical inference methods when the test set is missing, such as rejecting a zero hypothesis, is therefore subject to an error of unknown magnitude, making the result completely useless.
Am I right with the bold statement that statistical hypothesis testing is useless for real-world data, or am I missing something here?

IMDB ratings don’t have a distribution? I contest that notion. What is your argument for this stance?

You may want to read this wiki page; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong. Or, for a tongue-in-cheek expansion of this idea, the following lecture notes https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/tarpey.pdf

@Dave Please, precise the question. Do you mean a sample distribution or a population distribution? Ofc a sample of ratings has a sample distribution with its shape. I can't see any proof that they have a population distribution we can sample, tho. They are just a function of many factors. Basically, down to atoms, quarks, energy, and other stuff that physicists still have to research. But I can't see population distribution there. It's just a model, a way to simplify the reality.
This is how I understand it.

Unless you correctly condition on those factors, some of which will be weird like the rater having gotten a great job offer right before rating the movie, there is some possibility for variability. That means a distribution, maybe a weird distribution that doesn’t have a common name, but a distribution, nonetheless. $//$ Doesn’t quantum physics deal with probability distributions a lot?

Yes, you are missing something big --- the goal/premise of statistical inference
Your question here is close to this related question.  As with the linked question, you appear to be considering the merits and “assumptions” of statistical procedures without first identifying what they are actually being used for.  This leads you to a false premise where you ask about models and inference procedures without ever mentioning the thing we are trying to make an inference about.
I recommend you step back a bit before trying to evaluate the merits of statistical procedures.  First be sure that you understand the purpose that these are used for.  You have a set of data from some real-world sampling situation.  You want to use statistical inference/testing/modelling on this data, but for what?  What is it you want to know?  What unknown thing are you trying to infer?
One possibility is that there is no unknown thing you are trying to infer (i.e., the observed real world data is all that matters to you).  In that case your inquiry is limited solely to “descriptive statistics” for the observed data and you do not need statistical inference/testing/modelling at all.  If the data is the only thing of interest then we are in the fortunate position that we have observed it directly and we don’t need statistical inference.  The other possibility is that there is some unobserved thing that you want to infer, test or model.  For example, if you start with some data on movie ratings from imdb.com, perhaps you want to infer parts of the data you weren’t given access to (but which exist), or perhaps you want to know how some new person might rate a particular movie (that they have not yet seen/rated), or perhaps you want to know what the movie ratings would look like if everyone in the world rated every existing movie, or perhaps you want to guess the mean rating that would accrue if the studios release a new Star Wars movie (God spare us).  In any of these latter cases, there is a “population” of interest that is composed either of unobserved things that exist, or unobserved things that might hypothetically exist under some extension of existing real-world practice.
When we talk about a “population” in these situations, we are simply referring to the set of things that are of interest in a particular statistical application (each reduced to some quantitative/qualitative measure), consisting of the observed data points and also the unobserved things we want to make an inference about.  Collectively, this forms the “population” for which the observed data is a “sample”.  In the first example above, the population would be all of the imdb.com movie ratings (both observed and unobserved).  In the second example, the population would be all of the imdb.com movie ratings plus a hypothetical additional rating from some new person, etc.  If we accept that this population of quantitative/qualitative values either exists, or would have to exist for our initial question to make sense, then we must ipso facto assume that we have a set of values that are “the population”.  By necessity, we then have a “population distribution” which is the empirical distribution of those population values.$^\dagger$
One of the problems in the thinking exhibited in your question is that you appear to deny the existence of the “population” (or at least its distribution) while simultaneously invoking concepts on which this logically depends.  For example, I notice that you refer to the concept of “error” in your question, but what is “error” if not the deviation of your inference from the true value of the unknown thing being inferred (i.e., some aspect of a population or broader esoteric object like a superpopulation or parameter)?  You appear to be denying the existence of the population while using the concept of “error” on which it logically depends (an instance of the “stolen concept fallacy” $^{\dagger \dagger}$).
As to your final statement, yes, it is overly bold to diagnose statistical hypothesis testing as useless for real-world data.  Statistical hypothesis testing is used ubiquitously and successfully in science in many areas.  (It has its own problems and difficulties but none of these relate to what you have raised here. $^{\dagger \dagger \dagger}$)

$^\dagger$ In some modelling or inference procedures we go further than this by assuming the existence of a “superpopulation” which is an infinite sequence of hypothetical values that contain the finite population.  This is something that we use if we want to ask questions about “asymptotic” behaviours in a long sequence.  Again, the assumption of the existence of such a thing is often required for our initial questions (e.g., about asymptotic behaviour) to make sense at all.
$^{\dagger \dagger}$ This is a species of the stolen concept fallacy (see e.g., Kraft Jr (2018)).
$^{\dagger \dagger \dagger}$ The main drawback of statistical hypothesis testing has been the difficulties that accrue from testing a point-null hypothesis that is “close to true” but not actually true.  There is plenty of discussion on this site in relation to that issue, but it is not relevant here.

I fully agree with the paragraph about the stolen concept fallacy. Thank you for naming it so well. I'll add a clear goal to my initial question and remove the stolen concept fallacy.
Also, can you please share some links to the discussions about a point-null hypothesis problem?

@Maciek: This related question and its answers discuss the issues arising with testing a point-null hypothesis.


Am I right with the bold statement that statistical hypothesis testing is useless for real-world data

Much of the modern world has been built using statistical methods, such as medical advancements, so I am inclined to answer this in the negative.

or am I missing something here?

Yes, you seem to start with an incorrect notion that real-world data do not have distributions. Your logic after that notion might make sense, but it does start off by being incorrect.

For example, ratings of a specific movie on imdb.com are not sampled from any distribution.

I disagree. Sure, there is a combination of factors that influence the rating someone will give, but distributions can depend on many factors. Just look at even a linear regression that has a conditional distribution whose mean depends on the values of the features. After considering a bunch of factors like quality of the acting, directing, etc, there is still some random process going on, and so there is an entire distribution of possible values to give. Maybe someone rated the greatest movie ever after a movie date ended with a breakup and was so depressed that the rating was not going to be good no matter how great the movie was. Maybe someone else saw a bad movie but then was so over-the-moon happy to have a voicemail after the movie with an offer for their dream job that they would be inclined to be particularly generous in rating the movie. Maybe the person rating the movie just doesn't like westerns or romcoms and would always give a low rating for great films of those genres. Maybe there were disruptive people in the theater who ruined the experience.
Thus, I contest your starting notion that real-world data do not come from a distribution. They may not come from a common distribution with a name (e.g., Gaussian, Poisson, hypergeometric, etc), but there is still that random process that is nature, and we work through that data-generating process.
(Sure, this gets into some philosophy: is anything truly random, or are outcomes certain once we appropriately condition on other information? I am not sure where I land on answering such a question, but we never know how to appropriately condition on everything else, so the answer almost does not matter.)
We do get some convenient properties when data follow or almost follow the named distributions, but there are nonparametric and semiparametric approaches that do not make such assumptions. We have an active member of this community who is a major proponent of ditching many assumptions about named distributions and sees that as the way a sophisticated, skilled statistician should work.

I like @Dave's answer, I'll chime in on a different aspect.
While it is true that statistically oriented models often have more assumptions (and almost always more explicit assumptions) than machine-learning methods, the standard machinery of ML (cross-validation etc.) is not free of assumptions either. Critically,

we are always assuming that the test set is representative of the data we actually want to make predictions and/or inferences for. (The whole of point of both stats and ML is to generalize to data we haven't seen yet.) This assumption can fail, for example, due to non-stationarity. That is, our data are always based on something that happened in the past, and we usually want to predict the future; if the characteristics of the system are changing over time, then neither our training nor our testing set will be representative of the real data.
Biased sampling is another way in which the test set could fail to be representative of the data for which we want to predict outcomes.

the observations in the training set must be independent of those in the testing set. Typical methods for train/test splits sample the data independently at random; if there is some kind of grouping structure (spatial/temporal/cluster) in the data, then this assumption will fail. More generally, data leakage, where the training set somehow contains information about the test set, is a common and serious problem.


Both of these problems can be partially addressed, but doing so always requires more specific assumptions. For example,

we can do some kind of block sampling or cross-validation to mitigate independence problems — but we have to make some assumptions in order to figure out how the blocking should be done
we can incorporate some kind of trend model to try to account for non-stationarity — but we have to make some assumptions about how the system is changing through time


This is admittedly not quite answering the OP's actual question, just making a counter-argument that one could equally well make the argument that "machine learning methods are useless for real-world data" along the same lines ... if this attracts downvotes I will delete ...

I've spent a lot of time in my PhD thinking about this question as well. One quote summarizes the problem very well in my opinion: "We argue that psychology’s near-total focus on explaining the causes of behavior has led much of the field to be populated by research programs that provide intricate theories of psychological mechanism but that have little (or unknown) ability to predict future behaviors with any appreciable accuracy." (Yarkoni & Westfall, 2017).
But I also agree with Ben Bolker in a sibling answer that machine learning is no panacea. So that's why we decided to use both the prediction (machine learning) and explanation (hypothesis testing) paradigm in our papers (e.g., Huijzer et al., 2024). Our reasoning can be explained via the parable of the blind men and an elephant. In the parable, multiple blind men look at an elephant. One man touches the leg and concludes the object in front of him must be a tree. Another man touches the side and concludes it must be a cow. The moral is that humans tend to claim absolute truth based on limited evidence. I think it's the same for statistical methods. If you take your data and look at it via only one method, then readers might conclude that this result is the absolute truth. With multiple methods, this tunnel vision is less likely to occur and readers are more likely to get a better picture of the data.

Here is an an answer to a different type of question, but the question is fundamentally the same. In physics there is something called the "wave equation". In order to solve the wave equation we make the ridiculous simplification that $\sqrt{1 + \varepsilon^2} = 1$ (here $\varepsilon$ is a small positive number).
The first time I saw this simplification I thought it was a joke. How can we possibly take an entire term, toss it away, just because it is mathematically difficult to have it in the equation? There is no mathematical justification for doing that.
The answer is, the justification is not in the math, it is in the consequences of that simplification. Namely, if you use this wave equation model, solve it, and then compare to what happens in real life, amazingly it is an excellent description of how waves move.
If, however, this simplication lead to a wave model which was far from reality then we would not do that. Fundamentally, the way we judge our assumptions/simplifications is by seeing how well they describe the world.
To use another example, when dealing with planetary motion we might assume that sun and earth are points. In actuality, they are solid spheres, and we might even assume that their orbit is a perfect circle, as opposed to an ellipse. These are incorrect simplifications and there is no way to mathematically justify this. Other than to say, "here is what my model predicted and here is how close my prediction is to the actual result".
Statistical models are exactly the same. You make assumptions about distributions, you make assumptions about independence (Naive Bayes classifier), ect. There is no way to mathematically justify those assumptions. You just try them out, see how well they work, and if they work well enough, then you are happy with it. If they do not work well, then you might need to rethink those simplications and start again. But in the end you justify your models by how they work.

The point of the question seems to be that classical statistics does not have the “try it and see if it works” that machine learning has (which I dispute, but that seems to be the premise). Therefore, I do not see this as an answer to the question.
